# Using c++ template an argument to an objective-c method

Tags: c++, templates, objective-c++

How can I use a c++ template as an a parameter to an objective-c method?
essentially I want to do something like this:

```
template<typename T> 
- (void)method:(T)arg
```

but that doesn't work. according to [this](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ObjectiveC/Articles/ocCPlusPlus.html) document this is possible however it does not provide any examples. Does anyone know how tot do this?

Comment: Just checking, you are using .mm instead of .m, right?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No you can't do that.

> Objective-C classes, protocols, and categories cannot be declared inside a C++ template, **nor can a C++ template be declared inside the scope of an Objective-C interface, protocol, or category.**

Even if it is possible to declare that template, it is useless as Objective-C methods *cannot* be overloaded by type.

Answer (score 2):

When the documentation says "*C++ template parameters can also be used as receivers or parameters (though not as selectors) in Objective-C message expressions*", that means that you can **call an Objective-C method** from within a templated C++ class or function, not that you can actually make a templated Objective-C method.

For example:

```
template<typename T>
void f(id obj, T t) {
    [obj doSomethingWithObject:t];
}
```

...should work (although I haven't tested it). Of course, the type used when calling `f` would have to be something that could validly be passed as a parameter to `doSomethingWithObject:`, otherwise the calling code wouldn't compile.